# FrameRecorder$Exception: av_interleaved_write_frame() error -22

Tags: android, javacv

I am trying to record video using FFmpegFrameRecorder in Javacv library in android am getting a av_interleaved_write_frame() with error code -22. The error is thrown on executing stop() method of FFmpegFrameRecorder object. Find code below:

```
{
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (keepRecording) {

                        if (!frameModels.isEmpty()) {
                            FrameModel model = retrieveAndRemoveFrame();
                            frame = new Frame(imageWidth, imageHeight, Frame.DEPTH_UBYTE, 2);
                            byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) frame.image[0].position(0);
                            int start = 80;
                            for (int row = 0; row < 480 * 3 / 2; row++) {
                                byteBuffer.put(model.getPicture(), start, 480);
                                start += 640;
                            }
                            try {
                                if (model.getTimeStamp() == 0) {
                                    timeStamp += 40000;
                                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName()," Timestamp is Zero");
                                } else {
                                    timeStamp += model.getTimeStamp();
                                }

                                //Log.d("TimeStamp: ", " " + timeStamp);
                                frameRecorder.setTimestamp(timeStamp);
                                /*Log.d("Frame data", "" + frame.image.length + " count: " + frameModelCount);*/
                                frameRecorder.record(frame);

                                if (model.getAudio() != null) {
                                    frameRecorder.recordSamples(model.getAudio());
                                }

                            } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            ++frameModelCount;
                        }

                    }
                    if ((VideoCapture.TOTAL_FRAME_COUNT == frameModelCount ||
                            nextButtonPressed) && frameModels.size() == 0) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("Record ", "Before stop");
                            frameRecorder.stop();
                            Log.d("Record ", "After stop");
                            frameRecorder.release();
                            Log.d("Record ", "After release");
                            frameRecorder = null;
                            Log.d("Record ", "Successss.l......../");
                            keepRecording = false;
                            nextButtonPressed = false;
                        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                            long ts = frameRecorder.getTimestamp();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: av_interleaved_write_frame() error -22 while writing interleaved video frame.
```

01-19 17:52:54.816 20418-20450/com.example.user.videorecording W/System.err:     at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.recordImage(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:796)
01-19 17:52:54.816 20418-20450/com.example.user.videorecording W/System.err:     at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.stop(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:661)
01-19 17:52:54.817 20418-20450/com.example.user.videorecording W/System.err:     at com.example.user.videorecording.FrameMerger$VideoRecordThread$1.run(FrameMerger.java:146)
01-19 17:52:54.817 20418-20450/com.example.user.videorecording W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-19 17:52:54.817 20418-20450/com.example.user.videorecording W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-19 17:52:54.817 20418-20450/com.example.user.videorecording W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-19 17:52:54.817 20418-20450/com.example.user.videorecording W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Does anyone know av_interleaved_write_frame() is and what error code -22 means?